# Grails withNewSession does not flush

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-session

In a grails Domain a have implemented the `beforeDelete` as follow

```
class Shop {
    def beforeDelete() {
        Shop.withNewSession {
            Client.findAllByShop(this)*.shop = null                 
        }    
    }
}
```

But the client shop null value is not persisted to the DB.

If I add a manual session flush

```
class Shop {
    def beforeDelete() {
        Shop.withNewSession { s2->
            Client.findAllByShop(this)*.shop = null         
            s2.flush()  
            s2.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

It works, the client shop value are nulled in the db.

Is this a Grails bug or I have misunderstand the documentation?  Doesn't `withNewSession` imply an automatic flush?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation (scroll down a bit to the `beforeDelete` example [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)) seems to imply that flushing or clearing the session is not required.

[Burt Beckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith) has also indicated on the Grails mailing list (see thread [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Does-withNewSession-flush-when-done-td2287176.html)) that manual calls to `flush()` and `clear()` aren't necessary in a `withNewSession` closure.

With that said, there does appear to be a bug report (see details [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9946)) using `withNewSession` starting with Grails 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

`withNewSession` gets you a new Hibernate session, but it isn't necessarily transactional. It sounds like you want to use `withTransaction` instead of `withNewSession`.

Comment: So you suggest this way?

def beforeDelete(){
        Shop.withNewSession { Shop.withTransaction{
            Client.findAllByShop(this)*.shop = null }                 
        }    
}