# Hibernate issue with Database Migration Plugin in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have a migration with a "grailsChange" changeSet, which constantly 
generates a

org.hibernate.HibernateException: connnection proxy not usable after 
transaction completion

```
grailsChange {
   change {
      def list1 = [record1,record2]
      list1.each {
         DomainClass.withTransaction {
            new DomainClass(it).save(failOnError: true)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I noticed this too along with withNewTransaction. However withSession and withNewSession do not give this exception. Additionally the exception isn't exactly happening in the change set, as the changes are added. Its a final transaction outside the changeset that seems to be throwing the exception

Comment: I also tried withNewSession. It does not throw any exception but doesn't add records too. Not sure why but if withNewSession is workign for you then there must problem in the application somewhere.

Comment: withNewSession works if you add a ctx.getBean('sessionFactory').currentSession.flush() before you exit the closure.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. The solution in our case was, that we called a service method from beforeValidate of the Domain Class and the service was transactional. so Adding static transactional = false to the service fixed our problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when writing a migration that used `grailsChange`.  In my case, it would run hundreds of transactions successfully, and then fail on the outermost transaction that is most likely associated with the `grailsChange` itself.

Switching from `withTransaction` to `withNewSession` resolved the issue.

You [should not need to manually flush the new session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20558920/1475872).  If you continue to run into issues, I'd suggest adding `validate:true` and `flush:true` to the save call and making use of the `error(String message)` method in [`GrailsChange.groovy`](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/databasemigration/GrailsChange.groovy).

```
grailsChange {
    change {
        def list1 = [record1,record2]
        list1.each {
            DomainClass.withTransaction {
                def domain = new DomainClass(it)
                if (!domain.save(validate: true, flush: true)) {
                    error("There was a problem saving the domain.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```